# Order of reactivity of alkyl halides in Sn1 reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

**Problem::** Predict the order of reactivity of the following compounds in SN1 reactions .

i) $\ce{PhCH2Br}$

ii) $\ce{Ph2CHBr}$

iii) $\ce{PhMeCHBr}$

iv) $\ce{Ph2MeCBr}$

Answer::

SN1:iv>ii>iii>i

Reason:: SN1resonance due to phenyl groups.

I didn't understood why it doesn't consider loss of planarity as *two or three phenyls groups can't arrange themselves in a plane around one carbon atom* because of **ortho hydrogen clash** with each other which will no allow 
**Effective resonance**

Please provide some examples or explanation to it
Here is an example of loss of planarity in a compound with 3 phenyl groups[image]